# Create a class to get value from the derby database

Tags: java, arrays, derby

I have created a class to connect to a derby database. In the program, I created the table and inserted some fruit name as values. I just wonder how I can create another class to get the fruit name value in a new array.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class FruitDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate("drop table fruit");
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table fruit (name CHAR(15))"); 
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Apple')"); 
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Orange')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Banana')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Pineapple')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Mango')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Kiwi')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Grape')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Strawberry')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Pear')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO fruit(name)VALUES('Peach')");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM fruit"); 
        outputResultSet(rs);

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    private static void outputResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
            String columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);
            System.out.print(columnName + "   ");

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----------------------");

        String array [] = new String [numberOfColumns + 1];

        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
                array[i] = rs.getString(i);
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }

        }

    }

    private static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true";
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't understand the question exactly? Do you want to get the fruit names back from the database using a select query? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Actually, this is soem coding prepared by my tutor. I am asked to get the fruit name randomly to be shown on the screen. I have run the program, and all the values are stored in a column. I want to create another class to get the values from the array from the above program.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `array` you declared as a private variable, initialize it in a static block and add the getter and setter methods for it. There is no use of getter-setter here, but this is just for your understanding.

*FruitDatabase.java*

```
public class FruitDatabase {
    private static String[] array;

    public static String[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public static void setArray(String[] arr) {
        array = arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ...
    }

    private static void outputResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
    ... 
    while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
                array[i] = rs.getString(i);
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
    setArray(array);
    ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Then from the other class (suppose Display.java), you need to create an object of this class and then you can access this array :

*Display.java*

```
public class Display {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] newArr = new String[FruitDatabase.getArray().length];
    int i=0;
    for(String s : FruitDatabase.getArray()){
        System.out.println(s);
            newArr[i++]=s;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mtk, let me try. I hope I can do it!

Comment: Hi mtk, thanks for your great help. Actually I m really new with java. I just don't know where I should put the codes in the first part. This assignment is pretty hard for me.

Comment: Ok. I see the error as the `outputResultSet` is a static method, we can't use the above code as it is . Will update.

Comment: C:\Users\bauyeung\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\Hangman\src\FruitDatabase.java:32: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        this.array = array;
        ^
1 error

Comment: And the following for the Display.java

Comment: C:\Users\bauyeung\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\Hangman\src\TheHangman.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
 String[] fruits = FruitDatabase.getArray();
                                ^
  symbol:   method getArray()
  location: class FruitDatabase
1 error

Comment: Hadn't compiled and checked last time. Updated now and also compiled and verified. Please let me know if you get any error.

Comment: hey.. what's the error? It is working find at my end. How you updated your code accordingly.. Please verify.

Comment: it works..but how can I put the value into another array in another class, will look like arr[0]= grape and arr[1] = apple?

Comment: actually i m looking for the code in the display class which probably looks like the following:                                                                   FruitDatabase fd = new FruitDatabase();
 String[] fruits = fd.getArray();
    String ret = PickRand.get(fruits);
    System.out.println(ret);